# How does the python file reader stop if there is no actual "null" in python

Tags: java, python

I'm learning `python` at the moment and I'm having a hard time understanding how to loop through a file in `python` in comparison to `java`.

In Java I always use something like:

```
while ((line = br.nextLine()) != null)
```

while Python uses something like:

```
f = open("some.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines
```

How exactly does the compiler proceed here if there is no "null" in Python, would it be possible to "translate" that Java expression into Python?

Comment: `for line in f: print(line)` . Python uses `EOF` (End-Of-File) to recognize end of file. But in Python it is hidden so you don't have to bother this.

Comment: There is nothing here that loops through a directory. You have a Java loop that reads through a file, and a Python method call that reads the entire file in one go. You don't have any need to 'translate' `null` into Python.

Answer (score 0):

Python [None] are same to Java [Null] in meaning.
But you don't need to handle file pointer in almost case, `lines = f.readlines()`   in your code means: **Read a line at current position of file pointer and append it into [lines], then move file pointer to next line. Loop this operation until file pointer reaches End-Of-File symbol**